# In Javascript how can I make an Alert and modify html based on the contents of a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to take the contents of form fields (client, phone number) validate them (most likely using regex) and concatenate them into an alert and a modify some html so on form submit I get

```
<p>John smith
99999999
2 wilerby dr
morrowie city
morrowie </p>
```

and `alert("form data")`..

I tried with something like `var field1 = document.forms[0].elements[0].value`,
but not sure how to address the fields.

**Edit**:

```
<form id="form1" action="form_action.asp">
    <fieldset>
    <table cellpadding="3" border="0">
        <th> Order Details </th>
        <tr>
            <td>Client Name:</td>
            <td><input id="clientname" type="text" name="clientname" value="" maxlength="20"></td>
        </tr>
...
```

**Edit 2**

```
var name = document.getElementById('clientname').value;

function buttontest()
    {
    alert(clientname);
    }
```

using this script I keep getting a [object HTMLInputElement] alert, the script is external and the script tag is in the header.

Comment: Could you share html code of one of these fields? (e.g. name input)

Answer (score 0):

You should use DOM selectors alike `document.getElementById('elementId').value`.

Please read the resembling documentation about such browser APIs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document

Answer (score 0):

Try add an ID to those fields, and use `getElementById()`. Example.

```
var val = document.getElementById('id_field').value;
document.getElementById('id_tag').innerHTML = val;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clientName = document.getElementById('clientname').value;
alert(clientName);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you already know the sequence no of the element that you want to address then only you can use the syntax you specified i.e. as follows:

```
document.forms[form_index].elements[form_element_index].value
```

**form_index**->the index of the particular form where the element is.

**form_element_index**->the index of the element in the particular form.

So you could use:

```
alert(document.forms[form_index].elements[0].value);
```

N.B.-**`form_index`** will be 0 only if the form you refer to is the ***first form*** in your document.

### Otherwise

If you don't know either the sequence no of the form or the sequence no of the element in the form you should use the `id` attribute to refer to it(No need of any reference to the form where the element is) which is the **usual approach** and I personally suggest you to use this.

So in your code use the following:

```
alert(document.getElementById('clientname').value)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use **document.getElementById('ID')**, you can go to www.w3schools.com for more details.